# nhibernate CreateCriteria wildcard Like when

Tags: nhibernate, createcriteria

In SQL I can write

```
SELECT blah FROM Clients
Where @p1 Like '%'+lastname+'%'
```

How do I represent this with `CreateCriteria` in Nhibernate?

I've tried

```
s.CreateCriteria<Client>.Add(Restrictions.Where<Client>(c => "something".Contains(c.LastName))
```

but get an error

```
System.Exception: Unrecognised method call: 
  System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)
  at Hibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessCustomMethodCall(
         MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
```

I've also tried

```
s.CreateCriteria<Client>.Add(Restrictions.Where<Client>(c => "something".IndexOf(c.LastName) != -1))
```

but get

```
variable 'c' of type 'TrinityFinance.Data.Entities.Client' referenced 
from scope '', but it is not defined
```

**Note the order is important here.**

`@p1 Like '%'+lastname+'%'`

is not the same as

`lastname Like '%'+@p1+'%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a friend I've solved my issue.

`var searchCriteria = GetSession().CreateCriteria<Client>();`
`searchCriteria.Add(Expression.Sql(string.Format("'{0}' like '%' + {1} + '%'", p.ClientInputText,p.DbField)));`

`var results = searchCriteria.List<Client>();`

Comment: Note that this is vulnerable to injection attacks, assuming that ClientInputText comes from a web page. What happens if ClientInputText is "anything' OR 'x'='x'; --" ?

Comment: Yep I agree... not sure there is a better solution.

Answer (score 13):

```
s.CreateCriteria<Client>().Add(
      Restrictions.InsensitiveLike( "LastName", "something", MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

Comment: This will produce select * from clients where lastname like '%something%'. **I don't want this.** I want 'select * from clients where "something" like '%'+lastname+'%'

Comment: That is weird enough that I think you'd have to fall back to Expression.Sql and put the statement in directly. I doubt there's any direct NHibernate support for it.

Comment: .Add(Expression.Sql((? like lower('%LastName%')", "something", NHibernateUtil.String )) or something close to that.

Comment: hmm... trouble is how do you get the value '%'+Lastname+'%'

Comment: I would go for this answer, but i find the question kinda strange. If you do go for this answer, please note that if your database is case insentive you could just go for a like, that will use your indexes better.

Answer (score 0):

For Case-Insensitive %Like% Search

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Any.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(propertyName, value, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
 criteria.list();
```